# Proxying an address to another address

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I am trying proxy an address to an ip with path. Here is what I have done;

```
<VirtualHost 200.0.0.1:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@site-address.com
    ServerName app.example.com
    ServerAlias app.example.com

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/

    ProxyPass /index.html http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/index.html
    ProxyPassReverse /index.html http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

What I want to do is, when user goes to app.example.com, I want user the see http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/ content without changing the url. With this settings, when user writes app.example.com, the url becomes 
app.example.com/some/path/here/ and browser says 'Oops, you've found a dead link.'

What is my fault and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the order of the "proxies." As noted in the [`ProxyPass` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass),

> The configured ProxyPass and ProxyPassMatch rules are checked in the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So usually you should sort conflicting ProxyPass rules starting with the longest URLs first. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be hidden by any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL.

You might *also* evaluate the decision to turn on `ProxyPreserveHost`. This is unusual.

If you trying to have *anything* land on *just* "some/path/here/", i.e. trying to drop whatever follows `app.example.com/`, note that by default, whatever follows `app.example.com/` is being tacked on to the end of `http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/`.

To handle *that* situation, you will probably have to use the [`RewriteRule` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) with a [`[P] flag`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) set for handling by proxy.

See also the Apache documentation for [Using mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html).

Here is a starting point:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/index.html [P]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/ [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/
```

Comment: nope it does not work. still same thing happens

Comment: what is happening?

Comment: browser adds '/some/path/here/' at the end of app.example.com and browser says 'Oops, you've found a dead link'

Comment: try dropping the last /'s

Comment: if it is changing the url in your browser, that means that the backend server is doing a redirect, which is apparently not being handled there; this could be trying a directory index, fixing trailing slash issue, an actual redirect you have set up there ...

Comment: my configuration says, when app.example.com is requested show the content of ' http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/' and don't change the url. If url was chaged to sometihng like 'app.example.com/another-path', I would agree that backend server is doing a redirect but it is going to '/some/path/here'

Comment: The purpose of the `ProxyPassReverse` is used to show an "updated" url with respect to the reverse proxy "to avoid bypassing the reverse proxy _because of HTTP redirects on the backend servers_ which stay behind the reverse proxy." If no redirect takes place on the back end the browser url does not change.

Comment: For clarity, are you trying to have _anything_ land on _just_ "some/path/here/", i.e. trying to _drop_ whatever follows `app.example.com/`? By default, whatever follows `app.example.com/` is being tacked on to the end of `http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/`

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have tried what you wrote but url directly changes to 'http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/' which is not what I want

Comment: What happens when you comment out the `ProxyPassReverse` directive?

Comment: same thing happens, nothing changes

Comment: What happens with just `ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11:8080/`? And then with just `ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11`? And finally with `ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11/some/path/here/`?

Comment: ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11:8080/ --> infinite redirection

ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11 --> url changes to http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/

ProxyPassReverse / http://200.0.0.11/some/path/here/ --> url changes to http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/

Comment: Okay, I can't stay with this for now, but will check back. In the meanwhile, you might want to edit question to update where you are and, _for sure_ to clarify your desired end result, i.e. that you trying to drop whatever follows `app.example.com/`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the browser will only change what is showing in it's URL bar if it gets a redirect response.  This could be coming from the back-end server.  If you're piping requests for one URL to another server, make sure you're also setting the Host header appropriately if the destination you're piping to is a different URI authority.

Answer (score 0):

I have this configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.c-hack.de
  ServerAlias c-hack.de
  ProxyPreserveHost on
  ProxyPass / http://c-hack01/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://c-hack01/
</VirtualHost>
```

It works like a charm. Maybe the problem is araound the `<proxy *>` part. But I honestly don't know what you are doing there exactly.

Also I think this:

```
ProxyPass /index.html http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/index.html
ProxyPassReverse /index.html http://200.0.0.11:8080/some/path/here/index.html
```

Is not needed because it is included in the first one as this all obviously works recursivley.

Comment: I know this is neither from a credible nor a official source, but I think it might help.